# Redirect a user when he or she tries to navigate to a page in ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

Is it possible to re-direct a request for a page 'XYZ.aspx' to 'ABC.aspx', without writing any code? We are using ASP.Net 4.0 with IIS 7.5.

The idea is that we want to remove XYZ.aspx page from our website, and if users still use old bookmarks that point to XYZ.aspx, then we want them to be taken to ABC.aspx in an automated manner.

Comment: I believe you can do this with html tags. Have you search google at all?

Comment: Yes, I did my research before posting this here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. One needs to use the following in web config, and that's it.

```
<location path="XYZ.aspx">
<system.webServer>
  <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://localhost/mysite/ABC.aspx" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
</system.webServer>
```

**UPDATE** : This will also work if any query string parameters are passed to the page XYZ.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

there seems to be a few ways, link should hopefully help you out.
http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/iis7-redirect-windows-server-2008

Answer (score 1):

you can forward the user through web.config file or you can do it through IIS too. but I I were you I would use web.config. in shared hosting u cannot touch IIS.

Comment: Can you post how you could do this using web config? Thanks

Comment: No, its not shared hosting.